# Zendframework 2 Checkox

Tags: php, checkbox, zend-framework2

im pretty new to ZF2 and i have a pretty strange problem. I´ve created a simple checkbox using arrays, 
and set checked value to good and unchecked value to bad. But when i submit my form, the URL shows that when the checkbox is checked, it sends .....checkbox=bad&checkbox=good... I don´t know why.

```
class SearchForm extends Form {
public function __construct($name = null){
    parent:: __construct('Search');
    $this->setAttribute('method', 'get');
    $this->setAttribute ( 'enctype', 'multipart/formdata' );
    $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox',
            'name' => 'checkbox',
            'options' => array(
                    'label' => 'A checkbox',

                     'checked_value' => 'good',
                     'unchecked_value' => 'bad',


            ),

    ));
```

Comment: Zend adds a hidden (`unchecked`) checkbox - When using `GET` this is how all HTML forms work.

Answer (score 3):

Because by default `Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox` has `use_hidden_element` is `true`.

> If set to true (which is default), the view helper will generate a
>   hidden element that contains the unchecked value. Therefore, when
>   using custom unchecked value, this option have to be set to true.

You use `GET` method. Of couse, you see **two** values in query string: for checkbox and for hidden elements.

See more carefully [ZF2#Checkbox](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.elements.html#checkbox).

Comment: I already tried use_hidden_element => false, but then my checkbox doesn´t get sent at all.

Comment: @Markus I answered only why it happens when `GET` method (`checkbox=bad&checkbox=good..`). But, why you want to use custom values for checkboxes? Checkboxes changes logic state (`"true/false"` or `"checked/unchecked"`) of some parameter.P.S. I don`t quite understand what you want to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure this is the answer to the issue and not in a position to test right now but it is likely to do with the hidden element that the checkbox uses try:

```
$form->add(array(
'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox',
'name' => 'checkbox',
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'A checkbox',
        'use_hidden_element' => false,
        'checked_value' => 'good',
        'unchecked_value' => 'bad'
    ),
));
```